# Function is not listing in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Windows Spyder IDE Autocomplete is not working for me. [image: issue_image]

When I  press object+dot attached file window should come into editor but for me it is not working. Can anyone tell me what is the issue with this?

**OS :** Windows 
**Version :** Spyder 3.3.4

```
import pandas as pd;
pd.
```

Comment: Could you post a pastebin of the output for `conda list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue, see: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5782

The main problem is `enum34`, so running `pip uninstall enum34` should work.

Comment: i have tried. it shows warning that enum34 is not installed

Comment: Reinstalling anaconda solves the issue temporarily, but as it is a known issue I would advise you to either wait for spyder 4 or change to another IDE

Answer (score 0):

You can  use Acnoconda to downlaod the spyder from there. [Annaconda download link](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section)
As there is some issue while installing spyder directly you can check issue here [git hub issue link](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4587)

Comment: @Pradeep Yadav - It is already installed through anaconda link.

Comment: @Pradeep - please import any module and then using that module name press dot. you will be getting the autocomplete window

Comment: @pradeep - i have added the code above. Please refer it.